# CSS inheritance in stylsheet?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Can I do something like:

```
.background {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}

.text {
  background;
  color:#00FF00;
}

.text2 {
  .background;
  color:#00FF00;
}
```

So I can change both text and text2 background with one change?

Answer (score 4):

Not in CSS, at least [not yet](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/).

You can do:

```
.text, .text2 {
  background-color:#FF0000;
}

.text {
  color:#00FF00;
}

.text2 {
  color:#00FF00;
}
```

or

```
<element class="class1 class2"> 
<element class="class1 class3">
```

and then set the background on `class1`.

or

You can generate your CSS programatically, possibly using something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).